# What does back to back table references mean in SQL from clause

Tags: sql, pervasive

I am looking at a query from crystal reports and it shows a table name immediately followed by a table name. see below if that didn't make sense but I am trying to understand what this syntax is/does? thank you in advance for any insight

```
select * from {oj ((table_name table_name inner join ......))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd name is the alias. It allows you to refer to the table using a different name.
For example, you may want to shorten the references to that table throughout the rest of the statement in order to make things more readable. Or, more importantly, you may want to use the same table twice in the same statement (in which case an alias is required).

Comment: That's what I originally thought but in this case, it's the same name for the table. so it's literally just putting the table name twice. what's the point of an alias if its the same name?

Comment: It doesn't hurt but it doesn't help either.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah I took it out and the query ran just fine. Weird! must be a crystal reports thing. anyway, thanks!

Comment: It may help Crystal handle cases where the user remaps the data source (Database, Set Data Source Location...)